# NGINX sendfile and gzip

Tags: nginx, gzip, sendfile

The NGINX documentation says:

> Note, however, that because data copied with sendfile() bypasses user space, it is not subject to the regular NGINX processing chain and filters that change content, such as gzip. When a configuration context includes both the sendfile directive and directives that activate a content‑changing filter, NGINX automatically disables sendfile for that context.

However, if my gzip directive applies only to a certain filetype, is sendfile still enabled for other filetype ?